# JavaScript capture mouse click

Tags: javascript, onclick

basically when I click on a word twice in the browser, the word is selected. If three times, whole paragraph is selected. Now, if I have a canvas, and I click on it twice a text below of it will be selected. How can I block this in JavaScript? I mean to not select the text when I click on canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use CSS:

```
canvas {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```